# Integral of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

how can we compute the integral of PDE if both the PDE and integral is with respect to $x$?

For example:

$\int w(x) \, \partial_{x} \, [\mu(x)\,\partial_{x}\,u(x,t)]dx$

I know we have to do integration by parts, but how do we do integration of:

$\int \partial_{x} \, [\mu(x)\,\partial_{x}\,u(x,t)]dx$

The book says that the result is:

$\int \mu(x) \, \partial_{x} \,w(x)\,\partial_{x}\,u(x,t)dx$

I cannot get that result.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: $\int \partial_x f(x) dx = f(x) + c$?

Comment: Why is it like that? Is it because $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}dx$ and $\partial x$ will be eliminated by $dx$ ($\frac{\partial x}{dx}=1$)?

Comment: thats a little sloppy... but i will say $\partial x$ and $dx$ has no mathematical difference, its just notation to remind us that there are two++ variables

Comment: Okay, but how we can get $\int \mu(x) \, \partial_{x} \,w(x)\,\partial_{x}\,u(x,t)dx$ ? How $w(x)$ ends up inside $\partial_x$

Comment: You should refresh yourself on integration by parts, the derivative on $\mu \partial_x u $ goes to the other term in the integrand which is $w$

Comment: So if we define $\int a\,db = ab-\int b \, da$, what should be $a$ and $db$? Is $a=\mu \partial_x u(x,t)$ ? This partial derivative gets me confused..

Comment: you can use $$\int_a^b wF' dx = wF\Big|_a^b - \int_a^b w'F dx$$, where $F=\mu \partial_x u$

Answer (score 1):

You are integrating only in $x$. As such you should treat $y$ constant. Let
$y$ be fixed, and set $U(x) := u(x,y)$. Then we have  $\partial_x u = U'$, and the integral is
$$ \int_0^L w (\mu u')' dx$$

Integration by parts:
$$ \int_0^L w (\mu U')' dx = w \mu U'\Big|_0^L - \int_0^L w' (\mu U') dx$$
the boundary term disappears using the Neumann boundary condition.

PS note that $w:G\to\mathbb R$ is a one-variable function so some people would say you cannot write $\partial_x w$, only $w'$. The person who wrote your notes is not this kind of person, so you should get used to treating $\partial_x$ as a synonym for $d/dx$ if you want to continue reading.

Comment: Thank you, actually this is from a seismic book published by Springer